# Android: bitmap image not saving using compress method

Tags: android

This below method is not saving image into phone, i verified by searching imageName in my mobile using FileExplorer but nothing found. Whats wrong i am doing?

```
private static String saveToInternalStorage(Context context, Bitmap bitmapImage, String fileName){ 
        final String PHOTOS="photos";
        final String AUTHORITY= BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";


        File output=new File(new File(context.getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), fileName);
        if (output.exists()) {
            output.delete();
        }
        else {
            output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, AUTHORITY, output);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
            // Use the compress method on the BitMap object to write image to the OutputStream
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String absPath=output.getAbsolutePath();
        return absPath;//output.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

Manifiest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path
        name="p"
        path="photos" />
</paths>
```

Comment: getFilesDir() is private storage for your app. No other app has access. No file explorer has access.

Comment: @blackapps how to verify whether image is saved in the device or not?

Comment: Check Your Logs apply log.d("") method  @Albert

Comment: go to this path **Android-> data -> your project package name -> your mentioned path**

Comment: Your app can use File.exists(). Place a Toast() in that catch block to inform the user when something goes wrong.

Comment: @ShivamJamaiwar Where  in Android studio or in mobile phone?

Comment: Mobile phone file explore.